# HTML/JavaScript noob - onClick

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I'm trying to make a page which displays some text, and underneath that it asks for your name, and beneath that there is a button to submit your entry, which, when clicked, sends an alert saying "Hi, [name]!". This is what I tried:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script>
    name = document.getElementById('name');
    submitButton = document.getElementById('submitButton');
    function submit{
        alert("Hello, " + name.value + "!");
        name.value = ""
    };
    </script>

</head>
    <body>
        <p>Hi! I am learning how to build my own web page. Well, this is it.</p>
        <input type="name" id="name" placeholder="your name, please." value="Kabir"/><br><br>
        <input type="submit" id="submitButton" onClick="submit()" value="Click Me!"/>
</body>
```

This code might look absurd, as I am a complete noob to HTML.
I already provided a description of what it is supposed to do above, but it does not send an alert. What's wrong with it? Please use simple code, even if it comes at the cost of low-efficiency as I am just starting out with JavaScript/HTML/CSS (I didn't put CSS as it was very long and irrelevant).

Comment: Be sure to open the JS console of your browser, it would have answer your question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing parentheses in your code..and try get to  `getElementById` before call that function.

Function is written as a code block (inside curly { } braces), preceded by the function keyword.

Example:

```
function functionname()
{
some code to be executed
}
```

Try this code:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/qXDXC/1)**

```
   function submit(){
    var name = document.getElementById('name');
    var submitButton = document.getElementById('submitButton');
    console.log( name)
        alert("Hello, " + name.value + "!");
        name.value = ""
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing parentheses in your function definition:

```
function submit() {
    alert("Hello, " + name.value + "!");
    name.value = "";
}
```

Didn't you get a syntax error because of this?

Comment: Does your actual code have the parentheses, and you lost them when copying to SO?

Comment: Nope, that was the problem, but now it says "Hello, undefined!"

Comment: See Pawel_W's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Will you mind putting brackets after submit? Like this:

```
function submit() {
...
```

You can read some about functions here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp

Answer (score 0):

check this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/abhidev/s8AHs/1/

```
var name = document.getElementById('name');
var submitButton = document.getElementById('submitButton');

submitButton.addEventListener('click', submit, false);
function submit(){
    alert("Hello, " + name.value + "!");
    name.value = "";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you are trying to getElementById before DOM is loaded, which will fail

secondly, your submit definition is wrong (your forgot about parentheses)

here is your working code:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var name = document.getElementById('name');
    var submitButton = document.getElementById('submitButton');

    submitButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        alert("Hello, " + name.value + "!");
        name.value = ""
    });
}
```

and html

```
<p>Hi! I am learning how to build my own web page. Well, this is it.</p>
<input type="name" id="name" placeholder="your name, please." value="Kabir" />
<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" id="submitButton" value="Click Me!" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should always ensure that the DOM element is loaded before calling your function like this:

```
window.onload = function(){


}
```

Then, i recommend getting the name by doing a .value, like this

```
var userName = document.getElementById('name').value;
```

Finally, you should have this:

```
window.onload = function(){

function submit(){
var userName = document.getElementById('name').value;
  alert("Hello, " + userName + "!");

 }
}
```

Please keep in mind that it is recommended to not use the HTML onclick directly as it could pollute the global scope, and to use an event listener instead.